# Is it advisable to have more than one URL structures in a website?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo

I have a website in which the URL structure is `mysite.com/Anything_Here/And_Something_Here`.

I would like to have another section in the same site with `mysite.com/anything-here/and-something-here/`.

Does it make any problems? Is it advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, those are two different URLs

Nowadays, the preferred method, at least for Search Engines, is the use of -, instead of _

Comment: i knew that they are different urls but i need to know that whether i can use both URL structures in same site??